# LINQ-to-SQL - 'Sum' inside a select new

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, sum

I have a LINQ-to-SQL query that runs through a table, that I want to select 3 sum's - the sums of 'Rate' and 'AdditionalCharges', so I have something like this:

```
var sums = from d in dc.Deliveries
where d.TripDate == DateTime.Now
select new
{
    Rate = d.Rate,
    AdditionalCharges = d.AdditionalCharges
};
```

However, obviously this returns a new row for every delivery, which means I have to sum them up afterwards - which seems fairly inefficient. Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you use query syntax you can do something like the following

```
var data = dc.Deliveries.Where(d => d.TripDate == DateTime.Now)
var rateSum = data.Sum(d => d.Rate);
var additionalCharges = data.Sum(d => d.AdditionalCharges);
```

this is off the top of my head and not tested

Comment: Was just writing the exact same code when you beat me too it :)

Comment: Lol, I type much faster since being on SO

Answer (score 20):

I know that this is an old question, but hey, I found it, so hopefully this will help someone else...

You can also do this using Fluent syntax:

```
var sums = dc.Deliveries
             .Where(d => d.TripDate == DateTime.Now)
             .GroupBy(d => d.TripDate)
             .Select(g =>
                 new
                 {
                     Rate = g.Sum(s => s.Rate),
                     AdditionalCharges = g.Sum(s => s.AdditionalCharges)
                 });
```

Hope this helps someone...

Answer (score 8):

Not sure but you can try out the group bye function as below

```
var sums = from d in dc.Deliveries
where d.TripDate == DateTime.Now
group d by new {d.Rate,d.AdditionalCharges,d.TripDate} into g
select new
{
    Rate = g.Sum(s => s.Rate ),
    AdditionalCharges = g.Sum(s => s.AdditionalCharges)
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do this:

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Now;
var sums = from d in dc.Deliveries
select new
{
    Rate = dc.Deliveries.Where(n => n.TripDate == d).Sum(n => n.Rate),
    AdditionalCharges = dc.Deliveries.Where(n => n.TripDate == d).Sum(n => n.AdditionalCharges)
};

var result = sums.FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var sums = from d in dc.Deliveries
    where d.TripDate == DateTime.Now
    Group by d.TripDate // or primary key
    Into TotalRate = sum(d.Rate),
    TotalAdditionalCharges = sum(d.AdditionalCharges)
    Select TotalRate , TotalAdditionalCharges
```